# RSpec and Sidekiq: performing the queued emails so you can test their content

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, sidekiq

I'm testing my Rails 4 apps Sidekiq functionality with respect to sending emails. I have a simple question. My worker

```
 def perform(response_id)
    response = Response.find(response_id)
    micropost = response.micropost
    if response && micropost
       MicropostMailer.notify_question_followers_of_response(micropost, response,  micropost.user.email).deliver_now unless micropost.user == response.user
       micropost.followers.select{|follower| follower != response.user}.map{|follower|MicropostMailer.notify_question_followers_of_response(micropost, response, follower.email).deliver_now}
    end
 end
```

Sends several emails as you can see. The details aren't that important (I think).

```
  expect { MicropostWorker.perform_async(@answer.id) }.to change(MicropostWorker.jobs, :size).by(1)
```

...does what it should.

But I want to get at the specifics of the emails to test they are going to right people. Each time I....

```
    expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.length).to eq(3)
```

for example, I get 0, which I presume is because the emails aren't sent immediately. How to I "perform the async send" in the test so I can look at those emails

I saw

```
  perform_enqueued_jobs do
    expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.length).to eq(3)
  end
```

In another question but I think this is old....

Comment: In this case you can run the jobs "inline" which will run them immediately, and therefore you get the opportunity to check the specifics of the emails. checkout this page https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing

Answer (score 0):

Skip Sidekiq and test it like a normal Ruby object:

```
MicropostWorker.new.perform(fakeanswer.id)
expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.length).to eq(3)
```